# Android OpenGL change setContentView or setRenderer?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm working on a game for Android, it uses OpenGL 1.0. I have created a Menu, which was a simple activity with layout, but I didn't liked it, so I decided to create that too in OpenGL, which works, but I don't know how to switch to the actual game. I would like to do it in another GLSurfaceView, because creating everything in one then I must load all textures at the start which could be slow.

My question is that it is possible to change the setContentView or setRenderer somehow?
The basic of the app is like here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html#creating where setContentView is where I control Touch and Key events, and there I set the setRenderer to GLSurfaceView.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one activity and one GLSurfaceView, you can switch what you render by manipulating the renderer object.

```
public class MyRenderer implements Renderer {

Vector<String> modelsToLoad;
HashMap<String, Model> models;
String[] modelsToDraw;
Context context;

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    // load models ahead of time
    while(modelsToLoad.size()>0){
        String modelFilename = modelsToLoad.remove(0);
        models.put(modelFilename, new Model(modelFilename,context,gl));
    }

    // keep drawing current models
    for(int i = 0;i<modelsToDraw.length;i++){           
        models.get(modelsToDraw[i]).draw(gl);
    }

}

// queue models to be loaded when onDraw is called
public void loadModel(String filename){
    modelsToLoad.add(filename);
}

// switch to in-game scene
public void drawGame(){
    modelsToDraw = new String[]{"tank.mdl", "soldier.mdl"};
}

// switch to menu scene
public void drawMenuBackground(){
    modelsToDraw = new String[]{"bouncingBall.mdl", "gun.mdl"};     
}
}
```

Then in onCreate:

```
MyRenderer myRenderer;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    // set layout which has everything in it
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myRenderer = new Renderer(this);

    // load menu models
    myRenderer.loadModel("bouncingBall.mdl");
    myRenderer.loadModel("gun.mdl");

    // set up the glsurfaceview
    GLSurfaceView mGLView = findViewById(R.id.glsurfaceview1);
    mGLView.setRenderer(myRenderer);

    // set the renderer to draw menu background objects
    myRenderer.drawMenuBackground();

    // set the new game button to start the game
    ImageButton newGameButton = findViewById(R.id.new_game_button1);
    newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){            

            // make menu invisible
            findViewById(R.id.menu_linearLayout1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // tell renderer to render game scene
            myRenderer.drawGame();
        }

    });


    // make the menu visible
    findViewById(R.id.menu_linearLayout1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    // finally we have some time whilst the user decides on their menu option
    // use it to load game models in anticipation of the user clicking new game
    myRenderer.loadModel("tank.mdl");
    myRenderer.loadModel("soldier.mdl");

}
```

So rather than messing around with two renderer objects or multiple GLSurfaceViews, you instead have a single renderer object, and you just tell it what to render and when. You can manage it so that it loads models and textures only when you need it to or in anticipation of some need. Also it makes things easier if you decide to use the same model in more than one place. If you wanted to put a model in your menu that also features in game, you can just load it once and reuse as many times as you like!